# how to move past a drawer when point is on an org mode headline?

Tags: org-mode, motion

In org mode, say I'm on a headline, and just below that is a `PROPERTIES` drawer:

```
*** this is my headline, I want to move past the closed PROPERTIES drawer
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED:  [2024-01-31T10:54:33-0600]
:SOMEPROP: value here
:END:
```

I want to move past the drawer, to the start of the line below `:END:`. Is there some motion command that will do that? Something better than just `C-n` several times? Frustratingly, `M-}` in that situation says "cannot move further down".

Comment: You can do `C-n TAB C-n` to move to the drawer, fold it and then move past it. Or `C-n M-}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging through org source code, I found something that works. Hooray, I guess, for obscure, undocumented functions buried in lisp code... :)

This uses `org-end-of-meta-data`:

```
"Skip planning line and properties drawer in current entry.

When optional argument FULL is t, also skip planning information,
clocking lines and any kind of drawer.
```

When the heading is closed, though, it just moves point to the end of the visible line. For what I'm doing here, I want to open/unfold the heading. So I just need `org-fold-show-entry` first. The following two-line function is basically what I was hoping for here:

```
(defun org-open-and-put-point-past-drawers()
  "Show/unfold current entry and position POINT past entry's metadata.

The 'metadata' is defined by `org-end-of-meta-data', and we skip
past planning lines, clocking lines, and any kind of drawer."
  (interactive)
  (org-fold-show-entry)
  (org-end-of-meta-data t))
```

And then you add in some kind of UI for that. I've used `C-c M-n`, which reminds me of `C-c C-n`, `C-c C-x C-n`, and others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any out of the box solution. However, you could advise `org-forward-element` as follows

```lisp
(defun org-forward-element-ad (orig-fun &rest args)
  (condition-case nil
      (apply orig-fun args)
    (error (forward-line)
           (apply orig-fun args))))

(advice-add 'org-forward-element :around #'org-forward-element-ad)
```

and then simply use `M-}`.

Comment: That's not too bad, but still not quite what I was hoping for. Thank you, though! What I think we really need here are motion functions that work with drawers in the same way that, say, `org-forward-heading-same-level` and `org-previous-visible-heading` and friends work with headings, and that `org-next-block` works with blocks. I want stuff like that for drawers.